# restfull + url redirect

Tags: java, rest, redirect

I really googled a lot, looked for solution and examples but couldn't find any. 
My problem is, I'm working with java and RESTfull and everything I want is to redirect a request. 
For example:  POST or GET call : http:/test/test
and this should be redirected to any other URL. 
I need this for the Dropbox api. but response.sendRedirect(authorizePageUrl) doesn't work. My main problem is, how to get the HttpServletRequest  and the HttpServletResponse so that I can work with this. I really need help.

This is a part of my code :

```
@Path("/")
public class Dropbox extends AbstractHandler{

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
static String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
//@Context  static HttpServletRequest request;
//@Context  static HttpServletResponse response;

@GET
@Path("/dropBox")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
/*
 * This method calls the DropBox API 
 */

public static Response DropBox( 
        @Context HttpServletRequest request,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response){
    // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
    final String APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxxx";
    final String APP_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);



    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
        Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuth auth = new DbxWebAuth(config, appInfo);

    //redirect URL 
    String redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080/DropTest1/drop/dropBox";


    // Select a spot in the session for DbxWebAuth to store the CSRF token.
  //System.out.println("REQUEST: "+request);

        // Select a spot in the session for DbxWebAuth to store the CSRF token.
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String sessionKey = APP_SECRET;
        DbxSessionStore csrfTokenStore = new DbxStandardSessionStore(session, sessionKey);


        // Build an auth request
          DbxWebAuth.Request authRequest = DbxWebAuth.newRequestBuilder()
               .withRedirectUri(redirectUri, csrfTokenStore)
               .build();

          // Start authorization.
          String authorizePageUrl = auth.authorize(authRequest);

          // Redirect the user to the Dropbox website so they can approve our application.
          // The Dropbox website will send them back to "http://my-server.com/dropbox-auth-finish"
          // when they're done.
          try {
            response.sendRedirect(authorizePageUrl);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm really desperate.

NOT: I'm sorry if this has been solved somewhere else.

Thank you so much in advance!!!